# Wget gives up too quickly on a Express API

Tags: rest, express, wget

I want to download the result of a Express.js REST API which is very slow to process (~10 minutes). I tried few timeout options with wget but it gives up after few minutes while I ask it to wait around ~60 000 years.

```
wget "http://localhost:5000/slowstuff" --http-user=user --http-password=password --read-timeout=1808080878708 --tries=1
--2015-02-26 11:14:21--  http://localhost:5000/slowstuff
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authentication selected: Basic realm="Authorization Required"
Reusing existing connection to [localhost]:5000.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Giving up.
```

**EDIT:**
The problem doesn't come from the wget timeout value. With a timeout set to 4 seconds, the error is different: `Read error (Connection timed out) in headers.` And I have exactly the same problem with curl.

I think the problem comes from my API. [It looks like a timeout of 2 minutes is set by default in NodeJS.](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/150d6f124942617428c36728c023341c83166449/lib/_http_server.js#L256)

Now, I need to find how to change this value.

Comment: It's possible that 60,000 years is too long an interval to wait, that when converted to a 32-bit number it overflows. Have you tried using something normal, like two hours? `7200` should be more than sufficient here.

Comment: I updated the server for streaming the data instead of sending everything at once. Then I don't have the problem any more but I would like to know why I had timeout with my wget.

Comment: Have you tried using numbers under *two billion* seconds?

Comment: Yes I did that first. I just tried with less than 2 minutes and I saw a different error. I think my problem is from the API and not Wget, I edited my post. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
--http-password=password--read-timeout=1808080878708
```

is missing a blank. Use

```
--http-password=password --read-timeout=1808080878708
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a type when I removed the password.